# json with variable url doesn't work on mobile

Tags: jquery, json, mobile

i'm struggling against json on mobile with a variable url.
mobile browser can read correctly the data from some input fields with jquery, then I have to combine the values from the inputs to build up the correct json url.

this is my code, it works fine on desktop browsers but when I run the same from my mobile phone the script stops after the first console output.. getJSON never starts...

```
const account = "myaccountID";

$('#button').click(function(){
    var Name = $('#name').val();
    var Surname = $('#surname').val();
    console.log(Name, Surname); // this output works on mobile but then stops
  $.getJSON("https://mylink/api/"+account+"/item/"+Name+Surname, (data) => {
        console.log(data); // this does not work on mobile
    });
});
```

furthermore if I convert the url into an explicit url with no variable it works fine

```
$('#button').click(function(){

  $.getJSON("https://mylink/api/myAccountID/item/NameSurname", (data) => {
        console.log(data); // this is working fine
    });
});
```

can someone give me some help! thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect the issue is related to your variables. You may need to URL Encode them if they have unique characters or spaces. Can you check console on Mobile?

Comment: Constantly check name and surname  at mobile.